# What is the difference between DWORD and HANDLE type in C?

Tags: c, windows

I have a thread with return type `DWORD` in C but it is then handled by a `HANDLE` type pointer.

What is the difference between these two types?

I am asking this question specially for ANSI C.

It is right that `DWORD` is `uint` type and `HANDLE` is `PVOID`, and C allows to cast directly `DWORD` to `HANDLE`. But is there any difference in these types or can I simply say they are the same?

It is a question that was asked during a discussion. I want to know what the right answer is.

Comment: C "allows to cast directly" *anything* to *anything else* (except function pointers), so it's hardly an indication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Win32:

- DWORD 32 bit unsigned long
- HANDLE void * (32 bit pointer)

Win64

- DWORD 32 bit unsigned long
- HANDLE void * (64 bit pointer)

DO NOT just assume you can cast one to the other. It will work for Win32 and break when you port it to Win64.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question - there was no mention of Windows at any point, how is it relevant?

Comment: Both DWORD and HANDLE are Windows things

Answer (score 0):

A HANDLE is a PVOID or a void* typedef,
A DWORD is a uint32. Isn't a void* length depending from the memory architecture (eg. x86 & x64)?